# how should write a query to display data in dataList in asp.nett with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I want to display the result according to following table
[image: Click Here for image]

```
conn.Open();
        string str = "SELECT agent.name, COALESCE(SUM(sale),0) AS totalSales
        FROM agent LEFT OUTER JOIN sale 
        ON agent.name = sale.name GROUP BY agent.name";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str,conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataList1.DataSource = ds;
        DataList1.DataBind();
        conn.Close();

<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="container" CellSpacing="2">
<ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Style="font-family:Britannic;" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="totalSales"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

i write this code in server side but it dint work and it gives me error like

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'totalSales'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your post is mostly code, can you explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish, what behavior you're getting, and what you have tried to fix it?

Comment: i uploaded image in that you can see output..which i have to display in dataList..so how should i write code to display this output in datalist..

Comment: check what is coming in your ds object , there are some property name is misspelled or some other name coming from db end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="container" CellSpacing="2">
    <ItemTemplate>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Style="font-family:Britannic;" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("totalSales") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: still getting error (DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'totalSales')..i use this code too <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="container" CellSpacing="2">
    <ItemTemplate>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Style="font-family:Britannic;" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("totalSales") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>

Comment: try this  DataList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: still getting same error (DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'totalSales')

Comment: execute the sql statement in management studio and see the result and if possible attach to the question ,I think there is a problem with your sql statement

Comment: query runs proper in management studio  but it dint show in datalist...any  solution to show totalsale in datalist?

Comment: try asp grid view it's just need the data source so  ,and put a break point on    DataList1.DataSource = ds; and see what the dataset have . it must have the columns  totalSales